# angularjs-color-picker no color in picker

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, color-picker

I am trying to use [angularjs-color-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-color-picker) however the color picker doesnt show up with any color.

[image: the checkered area should be filled with colour]

I have added `"angularjs-color-picker": "3.4.8"` to package.json

I added angularjs-color-picker.min.css, angularjs-color-picker-bootstrap.min.css, tinycolor-min.js, & angularjs-color-picker.min.js to `gulpfile.js`

I included the module with `angular.module('app', ['color.picker']);`

And this is what is looks like in the html:
`<color-picker ng-model="myColor"></color-picker>`

Really stuck on why no colour is showing up. If I missed a directive I apologize, any input is appreciated.

Angular: 1.6 &
Bootstrap: 3

Answer (score 0):

You need to include tinycolor.js

Here is the codepen link, where colors are availble in picker.

https://codepen.io/swatifursule/pen/WJrmbB

**html file**:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinycolor/1.4.1/tinycolor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-color-picker/3.4.8/angularjs-color-picker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-color-picker/3.4.8/angularjs-color-picker.css">
<html ng-app="app">
<head></head>
<body>
  <color-picker ng-model="myColor"></color-picker>
</body>
</html>
```

**Js file:**

```
angular.module('app', ['color.picker']);
```

Comment: Thanks Swati I see your example works well in the codepen, however I still haven't been able to get mine to work.

Comment: Using the non minified files resulted in a 502 response code. Using the minified versions (the ones that were in the `node_modules` dir in the container) would fill the colour picker area with checkers and draging the mouse around gave this stace trace:

Comment: ```TypeError: o is not a function
    at t.value (story-tools-vendor-all.js:141980)
    at t.value (story-tools-vendor-all.js:141980)
    at story-tools-vendor-all.js:141980
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18380)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18649)
    at t.value (story-tools-vendor-all.js:141980)
    at t.value (story-tools-vendor-all.js:141980)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)```